# install EJBCA 6.5 in Jboss 8

Tags: mysql, jboss, ssl-certificate, ejbca

I am trying to install EJBCA 6.5 in Jboss 8 but when I run `ant install` after `ant deploy` I see this error:

```
ejbca:initCA:
     [echo] Initializing CA with 'ManagementCA' 'CN=ManagementCA,O=EJBCA Sample,
C=SE' 'soft' <ca.tokenpassword hidden> '2048' 'RSA' '3650' 'null' 'SHA256WithRSA'   -superadmincn 'SuperAdmin'...
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.
ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.command.CliCommandPlugin: Provider org.ejbca.ui.cli.keybind.InternalKeyBindingCreateCommand could not be instantiated
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
     [java]     at org.ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.library.CommandLibrary.<init>(CommandLibrary.java:53)
     [java]     at org.ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.library.CommandLibrary.<clinit>(CommandLibrary.java:38)
     [java]     at org.ejbca.ui.cli.EjbcaEjbCli.main(EjbcaEjbCli.java:29)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJBreceiver available for handling [appName:ejbca, moduleName:cesecore-ejb, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@1817d444
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:749)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:253)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:198)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
     [java]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getAvailableTypesAndProperties(UnknownSource)
     [java]     at org.ejbca.ui.cli.keybind.InternalKeyBindingCreateCommand.<init>(InternalKeyBindingCreateCommand.java:69)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
     [java]     ... 5 more

BUILD FAILED
```

my database is Mysql with this configuration in `{EJBCA_HOME}\conf\database.properties` :

```
datasource.jndi-name=EjbcaDS
database.name=mysql
database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ejbca
database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.username=username
database.password=password
```

I also have added this datasource to `{JBOSS_HOME}\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml`

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/EjbcaDS" pool-name="EjbcaDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
   <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejbca</connection-url>
         <driver>mysqlDriver</driver>
              <security>
                  <user-name>username</user-name>
                  <password>password</password>
              </security>
 </datasource>
<drivers>
<driver name="mysqlDriver" module="com.mysql">
   <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
</drivers>
```

when I look at my database I can see that all related tables to EJBCA has been created after `ant deploy`. I also changed the `logging.properties` of Jboss to `TRACE` but I can not see any information in `server.log`. What should I do to solve this problem and install EJBCA successfully in Jboss?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the username has privilege and access to ejbca database

then

```
ant clean deployear 
and ant install
```